# PowerApps - Need to combine two collections to a single record

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I have multiple columns in my SPO list and I've divided the columns in two collections.

I want to combine both collections so that it creates a single record on my SPO list.

Is there a way to do that? I tried but it created two separate items for both collections.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you have same record with multiple column, each record should have Primary key kind of Guid of record and so on.

Based on Primary key you can combine 2 collections into 1 combine collection and then user Patch function based on this combined collection to create/update records.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is there any documentation/article/video out there? I'm relatively new to PowerApps and haven't come across the principle of primary key.

Comment: Please mark it as solved if helps. In addition look at [this article for Primary Key for SP](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-add-a-unique-identifier-to-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/)

Comment: I checked the link you've shared. I'm using ID column in my list but not able to figure out how I can use that to combine two collections in one and Patch the same.